# PHP Array wont work Nothing happens

Tags: php

I can't manage to get this to work. What am I doing wrong? It doesn't give me any error, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php

class GameStruct
{
    public $Name;
    public $Game;
    public $NoticeLeave;

    public function Init($n, $g, $nl)
    {
        $Name = $n;
        $Game = $g;
        $NoticeLeave = $nl;
    }
}

$struct = Array();

function AddDefinition( $name, $game, $notice )
{
    $instance = new GameStruct;
    $instance->Init( $name, $game, $notice );
    $struct[] = $instance;
}

AddDefinition( "leavecsgo", "csgo", "Du har nu lämnat CS:GO-turneringen!" );
AddDefinition( "leavesmite", "smite", "Du har nu lämnat Smite-turneringen!" );
AddDefinition( "leavefifa", "fifa", "Du har nu lämnat Fifa-turneringen!" );
AddDefinition( "leavehearthstone", "hearthstone", "Du har nu lämnat Hearthstone-turneringen!" );
AddDefinition( "leavedota2", "dota2", "Du har nu lämnat Dota2-turneringen!" );

for($i = 0; $i < count($struct); $i++)
{
    if(!isset($_POST[$struct->name]))
    {
        $sql = $con->query("DELETE FROM comp_user WHERE Username='{$Username}' AND Game='{$struct->game}'");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please read the section on "how to ask questions". Thanks.

Comment: So it should work? Thanks for the anser Arkascha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it's a different scope in a function. So $struct in AddDefinition and $struct outside are two different variables! The $struct in function is a local variable and it lives just in the function. The outsider $struct is another variable.

This page might help you:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php